# How to create 3D pdf with Catia

Tags: pdf-generation, 3d-modelling, catia

how do I create 3D pdf with Catia - without converters or any other add-ins?

When I go to "Save As" I don't have .pdf option...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method to save it to PDF without addons.

You can save your project to 3dxml, but then you have to use special player.

**UPDATE**

I found a way in Catia V5 to [save to pdf](https://blogs.rand.com/rand3d/2017/03/catia-v5-tip-how-to-save-a-drawing-to-pdf.html).

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Actually I was told that there is a way! And without addons...In my work our partnes have send us coupple of pdf-s with 3D models of some tool. He told us that this can be done by catia - exporting to 3D pdf files and then open it with Acrobat reader

Comment: You can do it in 3DEXPERIENCE platform which can include CATIA V6 (or not, depending on your licenses) but not in CATIA V5. Note that you can do it also in 3DVIA Composer, also a Dassault Systemes product which can work with CATIA files. Otherwise, for CATIA V5, you need an add-on.

Comment: @jok23 please tell us more!

Comment: @FalcoAlexander I updated this post with a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a cheap add-on, check out Tetra4D. They have a plugin that will convert over 20 CAD formats to 3D PDF, including V5.